How to define a function as the Abs of a TransferFunctionModel?
Define a high pass filter first
ntf[\[Omega]_, z_, n_Integer?Positive] :=ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{"Highpass", n, 2   Tan[\[Omega]/2]}], 1][z][[1]][[1]]

Then I want to define a function f[x] that is the Abs of ntf while the parameters $z$ and $n$ are given
f[x_] := Limit[Abs@ntf[x, z, 3], z -> Infinity]

After that I want to solve f[x]==0.5
NSolve[f[x] == 0.5, x]

But I failed at the last step and the error tells me "ButterworthFilterModel::spec: {Highpass,3,2 Tan[x/2]} is not a valid filter specification."
How can I define such function f[x] and solve it, or how to solve the ntf directly?

Use this
ntf[ω_?NumericQ, z_, n_Integer?Positive] := 
 ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{"Highpass", n, 2    Tan[ω/2]}], 
     1][z][[1]][[1]]
f[x_] := Limit[Abs@ntf[x, z, 3], z -> Infinity]
NSolve[f[x] == 0.5, x]

This prevents call to ntf using symbolic cut-off frequency as it does not like having a function as cut-off.  Compare
 ButterworthFilterModel[{"Highpass", 2, x}]


With
 ButterworthFilterModel[{"Highpass", 2, Tan[x]}]


This way, numerical value is used instead which makes it happy.
But NSolve can't solve it. It gives

But this is separate issue.   Using FindRoot gives
ntf[ω_?NumericQ, z_, n_Integer?Positive] := 
 ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{"Highpass", n, 2    Tan[ω/2]}], 
     1][z][[1]][[1]]
f[x_?NumericQ] := Limit[Abs@ntf[x, z, 3], z -> Infinity]
FindRoot[f[x] == 0.5, {x, 1}]



Thank you @Nasser That's really a good method. BTW, I find the first ?NumericQ in defining the ntf can be saved.
